# How to retrieve the XML query in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008

> I use **XML** SQL query to retrieve top 10 values from tables then display
>   these values by asp.net page to pass the URL of the result page to
>   flash Game to print the top 10 values. I did my code well and i
>   retrieved the **XML** query well at aspx page .but I click on page to see
>   view source page it retrieved the **xml** values in HTML page but flash
>   game will not copy the values . so **how can i display the xml files in
>   xml page ?** .

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)
    fbid ,   
    Name as fbname,
    Score  as fbscore ,
    Img  as fbimg      
FROM 
    dbo.FB_Player
ORDER BY 
    Score DESC 
FOR XML PATH('Player'), ROOT('AllPlayers')
```

C# code

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fbgame"].ConnectionString))
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "procGetPlayerScore";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        c.Open();

        System.Xml.XmlReader r = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        string playersXml = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string theXML = Server.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Top10.xml")));
        lit1.Text= playersXml;
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter w = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Response.Output);

        c.Close();
    }
```

error after use new code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks off, it doesn't seem like its actually performing the write. Just off the top of my head, I would try this:

C#

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fbgame"].ConnectionString))
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "procGetPlayerScore";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        c.Open();

        System.Xml.XmlReader r = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(r);

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        document.Save(Response.Output);

        c.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: your about to solve it but i had this error " XML Parsing Error: junk after document element "

Comment: What was the actual error message? Can you post the xml output from running that query in SSMS?

Comment: I attached at the question

Comment: The line number for that error is 65, so it may be that you are already writing something to the response before this code executes, you could try adding `Response.Clear()` right before the line `Response.ContentType = "text/xml"`